# how template instantiation doesn't lead to linking error

Tags: c++, templates

I know that the following code will result in a linking error:

```
//first.cpp
void test(){
    //random code
}

//second.cpp
void test(){
    //random code
}
```

so lets say that we have this function template:

```
template<typename T>
T test(){
    //random code
}
```

and are doing this:

```
//first.cpp
...
test<void>();

//second.cpp
...
test<void>();
```

so the way I understand how compiler works is that it only cares for each file individually so it  only cares that `test<void>()` must have a definition therefore it will create one. same thing goes for the `second.cpp` then why don't we get an linker error at later stage when there are two definitions for `test<void>`.(I think this should be same as the first example where those two `void test()` functions in separate files lead to a linking error)

if this is a duplicate I'm sorry I literally didn't know how to search for this.

Comment: Template instantiations are implicitly inline. You can have the same effect with non-template functions if you add `inline` keyword, as in `inline void test() {}`  - this way you won't get linker errors in your first example either.

Comment: There are [several relevant questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+template+odr), such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664184/why-does-explicit-template-instantiation-not-break-odr).

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Please don't ask follow up questions after receiving answers. Go ahead and post a new question if you want to.

Comment: Others have answered in terms of the standard, but if you're interested in what's happening at a lower level, Google "weak symbol". You might also gain some insight from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229603/1405588

Comment: @o11c so if I understand correctly are all template codes _weak by default since we have established that they are NOT inline? because in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664184/why-does-explicit-template-instantiation-not-break-odr), the explicit instantiation with the biggest size is taken therefore its not ub and its actually following the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linker doesn't complain because the standard says so:

> #### [`[basic.def.odr]/13`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#13)
>
> There can be more than one definition of a 
> ...
> — inline function or variable ...
>
> — templated entity ...

In this regard, the linker handles them as if they were inline.

Note that they're not actually `inline` (for the purposes of optimizations). You can mark them as `inline` yourself, hinting the compiler that they should be inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `inline`

```cpp
//first.cpp
inline void test(){
    //random code
}

//second.cpp
inline void test(){
    //random code
}
```

This tells the linker not to worry about multiple definitions of that function in multiple translation units.
Templates have this without adding inline.